# What should i keep setLimit(int64) method to display all the records in Collections

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

**IN setLimit() method what should i keep to fetch all the records in data**

**packages - used : go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson**

**go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo**

**go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options**

```
findOption := options.Find()

findOption.SetLimit(?)

var res1 []Person

cur, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{}, findOption)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {

    var elem Person

    err := cur.Decode(&elem)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    res1 = append(res1, elem)
}

if err := cur.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Close the cursor once finished
cur.Close(context.TODO())

fmt.Printf("Found multiple documents (array of pointers): %+v\n", res1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to not call [`FindOptions.SetLimit()`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOptions.SetLimit) if you don't want to limit the number of results. If you don't pass a `FindOptions`, or you pass one where you did not set a limit, by default, results are not limited.

If you have a `FindOptions` value where limit has been set previously, you may set a limit of `0` to "undo" the limitation.

Quoting from [`FindOptions.Limit`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#FindOptions.Limit):

> ```
> // The maximum number of documents to return. The default value is 0, which means that all documents matching the
> // filter will be returned. A negative limit specifies that the resulting documents should be returned in a single
> // batch. The default value is 0.
> Limit *int64
> ```